# Firebase: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: V is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently updated my firebase version to modular and now my [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) query isn't working. Here is the line that is causing the error:

```
const q = query(usersCollection, where("interests", "array-contains-any", [route.params.filter]));
const users = [];
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  snapshot.docs.forEach((s) => {
    if(!interacted.includes(s.data().email)){
      users.push(s.data());
    }
  });
```

How can I resolve this? There was no issue in the older version when the code looked like this:

```
var snapshot = await store.collection("users").where("interests", "array-contains-any", [route.params.filter]).get()
```

Comment: What is `filters`? Where is it defined and what value does it contain?

Comment: @Philisonstrike I made a variable for route.params.filter in an array. Thats what filters is. You can now see that its the same value but still getting an error.

Answer (score -1):

Noticing that you've wrapped whatever `filter` is in an array, but haven't done that in the first example. Ensure `filters` is an array.

You are also not running the query. The `query` constructor creates a query object. It does not run it.

```js
import { query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const usersQuery = query(usersCollection, where("interests", "array-contains-any", filters));

const usersSnapshot = await getDocs(usersQuery);
usersSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
});
```

This will run the query and log the contents to the console.

Comment: I did these things but didnt include the code. My fault.

Comment: @chackerian in the code you supplied in the edit you’re still not running the query. Please compare my answer against yours.

Comment: The query is being run. This isn't a problem with my code as far as I can see. Firebase seems to be having issues

Comment: Notice that it says Type Error. It's not about code being run. Its about variable / function values.

Comment: @chackerian You can't expect me to know that without providing a minimal reproducible example. I have written you an answer that will work if implemented. From your question, you haven't provided enough information. My answer **has** covered all bases of your issue. If your issue is elsewhere, give us more to work with. Downvoting achieves nothing if it's not my fault.

Comment: It turns out this was an issue with a variable named query that was interfering with this function

Comment: Okay so keep the downvote on, since obviously it was my error.